# Cannot add AWS library to Eclipse Mars 5.4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have installed all SDK's from amazon - http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse
using `install new software` under `help`.But when I select `add library` in build path of project I get the following issue.I just cant select the path and click finish.
How should i add this?

[image]

P.S Before trying to add it manually, i faced this error due to which i removed it and tried to add it.

[image]

Comment: r u not using maven ?

Comment: @AmitK no...is it needed?

Comment: it will be much easier for you to manage the dependencies and aws has their maven artifact published , so you don't need to download each one seprately.